# Is it possible to run a code that skips Event Loop queue in the browser - runs immediately after scheduling

Tags: javascript

I was asked during the interview

> "Is it possible to have a piece of code to be scheduled to execute immediately - i.e. jumping the queue - without putting it at the end of event loop's queue".

Initially I thought that this is something done by `requestIdleCallback` (as I recently read about React Fiber), but after checking `requestIdleCallback` docs I'm not sure if this is how it actually works i.e. when current callstack gets empty and there was `requestIdleCallback` called, then ignore what is in engine's event queue and run the callback.

So... Is it possible or not?

Comment: "scheduled to execute immediately" ? maybe the interviewer was expecting a synchronous call ? Or maybe he was expecting `setTimeout(somefunction)` which isn't really immediate but almost. As it is, this question looks a little too open and vague for SO.

Comment: the `process` seems to apply to node.js - however, my question refers specifically to the browser environment.

Comment: `runs immediately after scheduling`,  What do you mean by this?, IOW: what scheduling are we talking about here.  If you did `let x = y + 1`, this will execute `now`, the event loop doesn't get a look in.

Comment: This bit might be what your after -> `however, callbacks which have a timeout specified may be called out-of-order`  So I suppose if you have a small timeout, the answer is yes..

Comment: by out of order I mean: imagine that `setTimeout(fn, 0)` is implemented in a way that adds `fn` to the beginning of the event loop or a mechanism that works like scheduling a microtask (e.g. `Promise` does that): https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, this is even exactly what the [*queue a microtask*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-microtask) task is supposed to do: push a new microtask at the end of the current job queue, i.e before the end of the current event loop.

This can be achieved by the quite new [*Window.queueMicrotask()*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-queuemicrotask) method (which is currently only supported by Webkit & Blink if I'm not mistaken).

```js
if(!window.queueMicrotask)
  console.error("your browser doesn't support the queueMicrotask method");
else {
  // idle
  if(window.requestIdleCallback)
    requestIdleCallback(() => console.log('five idle'));
  // timeout
  setTimeout(() => console.log('four timeout'), 0);
  // message event (beginning of next event loop)
  onmessage = e => console.log('three message');
  postMessage('', '*');

  // "queue a microtask"
  queueMicrotask(() => console.log('two microtask'));
  // synchronous
  console.log('one sync');
}
```

But even in browsers that don't support this method, we have since quite long time access to other methods that will "*queue a microtask*".

For one, `Promise.resolve`'s callback will get queued as a microtask, so we could also just do

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(functionToBeCalledBeforeEventLoopsEnd);
```

```js
// idle
if(window.requestIdleCallback)
  requestIdleCallback(() => console.log('six idle'));
// timeout
setTimeout(() => console.log('five timeout'), 0);
// message event (beginning of next event loop)
onmessage = e => console.log('four message');
postMessage('', '*');

// Promise microtask
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('two Promise.resolve microtask'));

// obvious microtask (third because Promise's as been queued before)
window.queueMicrotask && queueMicrotask(() => console.log('three microtask'));
// synchronous code
console.log('one sync');
```

But even before Promises, it was already possible to *queue a microtask*, by using the MutationObserver API, since [mutation records have to be queued as microtasks](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#queueing-a-mutation-record).

```js
// idle
if(window.requestIdleCallback)
  requestIdleCallback(() => console.log('six idle'));
// timeout
setTimeout(() => console.log('five timeout'), 0);
// message event (beginning of next event loop)
onmessage = e => console.log('four message');
postMessage('', '*');

// Mutation microtask
const obs = new MutationObserver(() => console.log('two mutation-microtask'));
obs.observe(test, { attributes: true });
test.className = 'foo';

// obvious microtask (third because Mutation's has been queued before)
window.queueMicrotask && queueMicrotask(() => console.log('three microtask'));
// synchronous code
console.log('one sync');
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

But beware, this also means that you can create infinite loops even if these methods are asynchronous, because the event loop would never reach its end.

```
const asynchronousBlockingLoop = () =>
  queueMicrotask(asynchronousBlockingLoop);
```

And for what `requestIdleCallback` does, it is waiting for when the browser has nothing to do anymore, and this can be in quite a few event loops.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather say "No", because of the way the JS runtime works and you cannot alter that from within JS code.

The runtime processes all events and tasks in a queue sorted by age (oldest actions/tasks/etc. are processed first) and the runtime "runs-to-completion" (meaning it processes each task from start to end before running the next task).

For example, if you write `setTimeout( <FUNCTION> , 0)`, the function *won't be executed immediately* – instead, the browser pushes a message to the queue and processes it *as fast as possible*. Even if there isn't anything else the runtime does at that point, the function is executed with a delay of a few milliseconds (note that the number passed in *isn't guaranteed to be the exact time when your function runs* – it instead resembles *a guaranteed amount of time which passes by* before the function runs). The same goes for `setImmediate` (where supported).

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

**Update**
The above *isn't exactly true for Nodejs*. In Node, using `process.nextTick`, you can place an action *at the front of the queue*. However, it won't be processed immediatly if the event loop already processes another task. Therefor, the correct answer should be "Yes, *but only if your code runs on Nodejs*, it is possible to place a task at the beginning of the queue. But it still isn't guaranteed to run *immediatly*".

Answer (score 0):

Since the event loop only processes timeouts that are in the queue when it starts, this should work on both Node and the browser:

```
function skipTicks(n,f) {
  if(n<=0) setTimeout(f)
  else setTimeout(() => skipTicks(--n,f))
}
```